# Will TCP connections be terminated when windows user logoff from its account?

Tags: windows, tcp, user-controls

I would like to know what happen to TCP connections when a windows user logs off and another user logs in on the same computer. Will the tcp connections created by user 1 be closed or it will be yet open in the background.
Thanks

Comment: Connections are created by applications. When user 1 logs off, his applications exit. Good written applications close their connections at exit.

Answer (score 0):

Connections depend on processes. Usually when logging off, user-initiated processes and their TCP connections are closed.

You can keep processes and connections open by switching users instead of logging off and on again.